# Why _ (underscore) of type Unit and () treated differently?

Tags: scala

I have a method which returns `Future[Unit]`, so when I call `whenReady`

These two options work: `whenReady(doItAsync())(_ => {})` and `whenReady(doItAsync()) { _ => }`

but this doesn't: `whenReady(doItAsync())(() => {})`

**Are not `_` of type `Unit` and empty params list equivalent in this case?**

Comment: No, `_` means an unused parameter of *any* type.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Bergi I am getting `Type mismatch, expected: Unit => NotInferredU, actual: () => Unit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although type `Unit` is similar to `void` from other languages it is not exactly the same.
This particular trouble comes from a limitation in Java (and thus Scala) generics implementation: they are implemented using [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Particularly it means that generic method can't change the number of arguments. Now what happens when type parameter is `Unit`? We still must have the same number of arguments and also can't magically change return type to return nothing (`void`) because this will be a different signature. So the answer is to use some fake type with only fakes values: `scala.runtime.BoxedUnit`. And thus `Unit` might represent actual parameter that you don't need but has to be there. And so type signature `() => {}` doesn't match that because it takes no parameters.

Note also that in Java itself there is the same issue and thus there is a similar thing called [`java.lang.Void`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)

**Update**:

To make the point more clear consider following generic vs. non-generic code:

```
def foo(f: () => String) = println(f())

def fooGeneric[T](arg: T, f: (T) => String) = println(f(arg))

foo(() => "Non-generic")
fooGeneric[Unit]((), (_) => "generic")
```

Note that also logically `fooGeneric[Unit]` is the same as `foo`, you still have to pass first argument and pass function that accept an (useless) argument as the second parameter.

Comment: But the types are inferred at compile time. The compiler just does not accept `() => {}` as a valid equivalence of `_ => {}` in case when `_` is of type `Unit`.

Comment: @PavelVoronin, I don't see good reasons why Scala compiler couldn't theoretically coerce type `Function0[String]` into `Function1[Unit, String]` in this particular case but it doesn't do it (probably this is hard to do consistently).  `whenReady` second argument type is `Function1[T,U]` and on the JVM level this is quite different from `Function0[String]` and thus you have to pass something that matches `Function1`. If the `Future` and `whenReady` were not generic, the code with `() => {}` would work. The code doesn't compile because they are generic.

Comment: That's how C# works: clear distinction between `void DoIt<T>(Action<T> act)`, `U DoIt<T,U>(Func<T, U> func)`, `U DoIt<U>(Func<U> func)` and void DoIt(Action act)`. So I'd say I like this generalisation =)

Comment: @PavelVoronin, **_type erasure_** although being kind of implementation details for generics is actually crucial here. For you as a C# developer there is a question to ask yourself: why in Java when generics were introduced all the standard collection types were left as is but in .Net they "cloned" them into new `System.Collections.Generics` namespace? The answer is different implementations that require different trade-offs.

Comment: @PavelVoronin, probably a better .Net illustration for the distinction would be the question why in .Net there are separate `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` and `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>` while in Scala there is only `Future[T]`. My answer is that in .Net you just can't have `Task<void>` while in Scala you can have `Future[Unit]` but with some fake arguments that still has to be passed and consumed. P.S. Have you also looked at the code in my update? Do you get the difference?

Comment: Yes, sure. And I'd like to have single `Task<T>` where `T` could be `void`. At least F# tried to make it as general as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Are not _ of type Unit and empty params list equivalent in this case?

No. `_ => {}` defines a function with single parameter (which happens in this context to have type `Unit`), `() => {}` defines a function with no parameters. Their types are `Unit => Unit` and `() => Unit`, or without syntactic sugar `Function1[Unit, Unit]` and `Function0[Unit]`. These types aren't actually related: neither of them is a subtype of the other.

You can write a single-argument anonymous function taking `Unit` with `()` using pattern-matching: `{ case () => ... }`. But there is no point to doing that.